# How can I use the Query Editor for Amazon Aurora v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

Currently, I have created an Aurora Serverless v2 MySQL database cluster.

When it comes to using the Query editor I get the following message:

> No databases that support query editor
>
> Currently, query editor only supports Aurora Serverless databases. Only Aurora Serverless database that you have access to will be displayed.
>
> To use the query editor for a database, the database must have the Data API enabled.

The Data API option in the *Additional Connectivity* section isn't available anymore and I couldn't find it so I skipped it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supported now! Just launched in Dec

Comment: How? I don't see any options to enable the Data API.

Comment: In my case I'm using a MySQL serverless v2 database cluster, and it appears that currently only PostGres serverless v2 is supported (as per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.enabling)).

Answer (score 9):

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/query-editor.html):

> The Data API and query editor aren't supported for Aurora Serverless v2.

> The query editor is available only for Aurora Serverless v1 DB clusters using specific Aurora MySQL and Aurora PostgreSQL versions that support the Data API.

Comment: Then how can I create tables in the database cluster?

Comment: Connect to the database using the credentials and then run your commands?

Comment: Just one more question, did you mean using the credentials and running the code using AWS CLI? Can I do so using aws cdk too?

Comment: Can't believe there's no way to query in the console in AWS, what a pain.

Comment: Thanks @ErmiyaEskandary for your answer. I updated the acceptance of the answer as there has been a more updated answer

Answer (score 1):

They have enabled data api for serverless v2, but limited to specific location(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.Data_API.html)

Comment: Links tends to be dead after some time, can you copy the relevant informations in your answer ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).